# The container app sample published by Google does not work properly

Tags: firebaseui, google-cloud-run, identity-aware-proxy

I want to create an app for login authentication using firebaseui in Cloud Run.
So, at first, I executed all the items after "Contributions" of the following URL published by Google.
However, on the screen of the created app, only the characters "Loading ..." were displayed.
Please let me know if there is any other work required.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/iap-gcip-web-toolkit/tree/master/authui-container

Comment: Do you get any errors in your browser console or anything that might hint into what is causing the issue?

Comment: Nothing is displayed in the browser console.
The following was displayed in the Cloud Run service log.

`GET 404 648 B10 msChrome 87 https://[SERVICE_NAME]/static/script.js`

Comment: Weird thing, because a 404 is a not found. This is quite an odd log you got, I would advise you to remove this service and do it all from scratch, I believe it would be faster to fix it.